# maven-assembly-plugin depdencySet not being included

Tags: maven-3, puppet, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to include a dependency in my maven module but it doesn't appear to be working, the following is what I have:

```
<dependencySet>
   <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
      <includes>
           <include>com.sam:myWebApp</include>
      </includes>
      <outputDirectory>/mywebapp/files</outputDirectory>
       <unpack>false</unpack>
</dependencySet>
```

The full code is in my github repo:
https://github.com/darkcloudi/PuppetExample/tree/master/puppet/exampleWebApp

When I build my parent pom it builds 2 modules:
1.) the webapp which was created using mvn archetype (a simple app)
2.) a puppet module

What I want is when the puppet maven project is built the webapp to appear in the files directory so me including the dependencySet and specifying it in the directory should work, shouldn't it? I cannot see where I am going wrong, its should be as simple as including the war dependency to the files folder.

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but it worked with moduleSets:

```
 <moduleSets>
        <moduleSet>
            <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
             <includes>
                <include>com.sam:myWebApp:*:*</include>  
            </includes>
           <binaries>
                <outputDirectory>myWebApp/files</outputDirectory>
                <unpack>false</unpack>
            </binaries>
        </moduleSet>
    </moduleSets>
```